# Why does the washing machine cause water hammer in the pipes in my bathroom?

Tags: water-hammer

We recently replaced the valve in our bathtub/shower as hot water would not go to the shower faucet.  Now every time the washing machine fills (located downstairs other side of house), the pipes bang very loudly in the bathroom where the valve was fixed.  Does this mean the valve is faulty or needs to be replaced again?

Answer (score 2):

Pipes normally bang because they are banging against something.  Try securing them.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem made me curious, so I did a little research and found something that I hope will help you out: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-quiet-noisy-water-pipes.html.  Good luck.

Comment: Answers that consist of only links, are only useful while the link is working. Consider summarizing the linked content, so the information can live on longer than the link.

Comment: I think the link is well written and could be helpful to this user, so anything I said would be redundant. Also, I just don't have the time to thoroughly read posts like this and restate them. Whether the link works in the future seems secondary to me.

Comment: In that case, you should post the link in a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to remember to do this in the future.